# CosmosDB GeoSpatial Points Invalid

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, geospatial

I'm using Azure's cosmos DB, and testing via the sqlquery in the Azure portal. Some points in my collection are valid, some are not. I am unable to tell from the GeoJSON spec if I am missing requirements. All my points pass the geojsonlint test: https://geojsonlint.com/

What could be causing invalid points? The locations are setup the same as far as I can tell.

My Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM events1 e
WHERE ST_ISVALID(e.location)
```

Running the query returns that these are valid:

```
[
{
    "id": "b4b49b65-dfad-40f3-943b-753553507d2c",
    "name": "OG Olympics",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            41.900697426935544,
            12.480266913771628
        ]
    },
    "events": "Hockey",
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "recurring": null,
    "date": null,
    "difficulty": "Expert",
    "ages": "Senior",
    "admin": null,
    "private": null,
    "_rid": "Maw1AIaRiRoHAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/Maw1AA==/colls/Maw1AIaRiRo=/docs/Maw1AIaRiRoHAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"11003fb9-0000-0700-0000-5f2f15cf0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1596921295
},
{
    "id": "f2d063e3-5654-475d-8e97-7412dc77fcfb",
    "name": "Test Event DenverCC",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            100.2093,
            -15.868
        ]
    },
    "events": "Basketball",
    "time": "18:00:00",
    "recurring": null,
    "date": null,
    "difficulty": "Intermediate",
    "ages": "Senior",
    "admin": null,
    "private": null,
    "_rid": "Maw1AIaRiRoJAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/Maw1AA==/colls/Maw1AIaRiRo=/docs/Maw1AIaRiRoJAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"1300a79d-0000-0700-0000-5f304fc80000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1597001672
},
{
    "id": "10000",
    "name": "OG Olympics 2",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            41.000697426935545,
            -12.080266913771627
        ]
    },
    "events": "Hockey",
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "recurring": null,
    "date": null,
    "difficulty": "Expert",
    "ages": "Senior",
    "admin": null,
    "private": null,
    "_rid": "Maw1AIaRiRoKAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/Maw1AA==/colls/Maw1AIaRiRo=/docs/Maw1AIaRiRoKAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"13003499-0000-0700-0000-5f304d580000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1597001048
}
```

]

But it returns that these are invalid:

```
   {
    "id": "1000",
    "name": "Sunday Morning Hockey",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            39,
            -105
        ]
    },
    "events": "hockey",
    "time": "09:00",
    "recurring": "true",
    "date": "2020-08-02",
    "difficulty": "all levels",
    "ages": "all ages",
    "admin": "1000",
    "private": "false",
    "_rid": "Maw1AIaRiRoBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/Maw1AA==/colls/Maw1AIaRiRo=/docs/Maw1AIaRiRoBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"13008c9f-0000-0700-0000-5f3050d70000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1597001943
}

{
    "id": "9f373e04-0cfc-4121-927d-a6256dbe06c6",
    "name": "test1",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            39.731441899363105,
            -104.98381230980158
        ]
    },
    "events": "Basketball",
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "recurring": null,
    "date": null,
    "difficulty": "Expert",
    "ages": "Adult",
    "admin": null,
    "private": null,
    "_rid": "Maw1AIaRiRoLAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/Maw1AA==/colls/Maw1AIaRiRo=/docs/Maw1AIaRiRoLAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"13005999-0000-0700-0000-5f304d760000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1597001078
}

{
    "id": "be01bc12-d28e-4368-b6de-0f3e84dbe13c",
    "name": "test2",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            39.72082849205111,
            -104.98461395502092
        ]
    },
    "events": "Hockey",
    "time": "00:00:00",
    "recurring": null,
    "date": null,
    "difficulty": "Expert",
    "ages": "Adult",
    "admin": null,
    "private": null,
    "_rid": "Maw1AIaRiRoMAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/Maw1AA==/colls/Maw1AIaRiRo=/docs/Maw1AIaRiRoMAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"1300219a-0000-0700-0000-5f304de10000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1597001185
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to realize, but GeoJSON expects flipped coordinates in the Point.
So while Maps return me a point type with [ latitude, longitude ]. GeoJSON expects [longitude, latitude]